# TYPO3 change tca config type dynamically

Tags: typo3

I wanted to change the tca field config type depending on the previous filed value.
For example there are two fields field_one and field_two as shown below

```
'field_one' => array(
 'exclude' => 0,
 'label' => 'field1',
 'config' => array(
  'type' => 'select',
  'foreign_table' => 'tx_ext_domain_model_field',
  'default' => 1,
  'minitems' => 0,
  'maxitems' => 1,
 ),
),

'field_two' => array(
 'exclude' => 0,
 'label' => 'field two',
 'config' => array(
  'type' => 'input',
  'eval' => 'trim'
 ),
),
```

Here what I need is if the field_one value is 2,I need to load different full config array for field_two.

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html for the entries `type` and `requestUpdate`.

As the field configurations are static, you cannot change them. However you can change the visual appearance (order of fields).

I suggest to create two different fields.

Comment: "field configurations are static, you cannot change them" - this is unfortunately correct.

Comment: You might want to have a look at ``columnsOverrides`` https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Types/Index.html#columnsoverrides

Answer (score -1):

You want to check out displayCond

Comment: In displayCond we can set to show or hide a field but can not change only config array.

Comment: What exactely is the difference over "none"?